# employee leave count values in jquery ajax in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to display the total no of count values in casual and personal leave. For example if i choose casual leave, total no of causual leave count as 6 and personal leave count as 12 (mention in leavetype table attached in screenshots) and how many of days they have to use(mention in leave_application table attached in screenshots)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHu6P.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz0DK.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTxr0.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCpnV.jpg)

This is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
      $('#select').change(function()
      { 
        showval=$(this).val();  
        $.ajax({  
          type:'GET',
          url: '<?php echo $base_url;?>user/ajaxleave',         
          data : { 'employee_id': showval}, 
          success:function(data)
          {    
            countleave = $('.productprice-'+showval).val(data);  
            $('.show_selected').html(`Your Total leave: ${countleave}  and your remaining leave : ${countleave}`);
          },
        });          
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is my view code :

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div>
                <label class="form-control-label">Leave Type</label>
                  <select name="leavetype" class="form-control" id="select">
                      <option value="select">Select</option>  
                        <?php foreach($leavetype as $leaveappln_info){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $leaveappln_info->leavetype_id?>"><?php echo $leaveappln_info->leavetype_name; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>  
                  </select>
              </div>
          </div>   
          <div class="show_selected"></div>
          <input type="hidden"  value="" id="hiddenval"> 
          <input type="hidden" value="" class="productprice" id="productprice">

          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div>
                  <label class="form-control-label">Start Date</label>
                  <input type="date" name="start_date" class="form-control startdate" placeholder="Start Date" id="startdate" required onchange="cal()">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div>
                  <label class="form-control-label">End Date</label>
                  <input type="date" name="end_date" class="form-control enddate" placeholder="End Date" id="enddate" required onchange="cal()">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div>
                  <label class="form-control-label">Count Days</label>
                  <input type="text" name="count_days" class="form-control" placeholder="Count Days" id="countdays" readonly>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div>
                  <label class="form-control-label">Reason</label>
                  <textarea name="reason" class="form-control" placeholder="Reason"> </textarea> 
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

This is my Controller :

```
public function ajaxleave()
{
    $employee_id = $this->input->get('employee_id');     
    $this->db->where('leaveappln_id',$employee_id); 
    $result=$this->db->get('leave_application')->row();  

    $this->db->where('leavetype_id',$result->leavetype);
    $leavetype=$this->db->get('leavetype')->row();  
    echo $leavetype->leavetype_name;            
}
```

My expected result will be Total leave count from leavetype table and remaining leave will be calculated from leave_application table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtnK2.png)

Comment: Add schema instead of image would be better..

Comment: I have only less no of reputation so image will not be displayed

Comment: not image.... db schema i told...like create table,insert into those sql commands

Comment: Yes Okay....@MohammedShafeek

Comment: why are you using 'duration' and 'employeetype' columns?

Comment: Duration means personal leave has to be taken once a month and casual leave has 2 months once......employeetype as fresher experienced and such(taken from another table so that showed only id)

Comment: Add your schema in question so that u could have a chance get all data in single query..

Comment: I dont know how to add schema pls guide me..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199720/discussion-between-mohammed-shafeek-and-sixthstar).